# Programmatic start NSSlider dragging

Tags: cocoa, nsslider

I would like to start a slider action programmatically. So pressing on some text in a `NSTextView` that displays a slider also automatically starts the `mousedown` event on the slider so you can drag immediately instead of pressing twice. What approach should i take on this? Should i listen for global mouse events and then manually update the slider position, or can i somehow imitate the systems `mouseDown` / `mouseMoved` calls on the `NSSlider`?